# Duplicate breadcrumbs but they're not in the $breadcrumb variable?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm trying to remove this duplicate breadcrumb but I don't see what's generating it. Any ideas?
[image: Breadcrumb and dpm($breadcrumbs)]

Comment: Are you using any breadcrumb modules?

Comment: Of course I left that out. This theme is built on top of the WetKit variant but the Wet_breadcrumbs module is turned off. I turned off all breadcrumb modules and that seemed to have fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was an easy one: turn off custom breadcrumb modules...